# Уважаемые, помогите, пожалуйста, никак не могу разобраться, как правильно писать. Если это вообще неверно, то как правильно?

Tags: грамматика

Он поступил в соответствии высших(им) морально-нравственных(ым) качеств(ам) человека.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Он поступил **в соответствии с** высшими морально-нравственными качествами человека.*

**СООТВЕТСТВИЕ,** ср. Соотношение между чем-л., выражающее согласованность, равенство в каком-л. отношении. С. производственных отношений характеру производительных сил. Полное с. интересов. Нарушено с. между частями здания. С. между окраской животного и цветом окружающей среды. С. формы и содержания. Найти словам подлинника с. в языке перевода. **<В соответствии с чем. в зн. предлога.** В соответствии с планом, с графиком.

СООТВЕТСТВИЕ **чему / между чем / с чем.**

Сравнить:

Должно быть соответствие между моралью и поступками человека.

Соответствие  моральных принципов человека и его поступков очень важно.

Answer (score 1):

[В СООТВЕТСТВИИ С (чем)](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=124), *предлог* — требуется творительный падеж.

Правильно так:
*Он поступил в соответствии с* (чем?) *высш**ими** морально-нравственн**ыми** качеств**ами** человека.*

Уже одного только её отказа от участия в боях было бы достаточно, чтобы вынудить византийцев **поступить в соответствии с договорённостями.**
Инквизиция поступила **в соответствии со своими принципами...**

[Предложения со словосочетанием «поступить в соответствии»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B8)